# How to find folder paths that have existed in the past on a PC's hard drive

Tags: path, cache, recovery

I have a folder named `fubar` on a PC, having the path `D:\Foo\fubar`.

The folder `fubar` was previously named differently and was stored in a different path named `D:\Baz\Qux\`

I need to find out what the folder `fubar` was called previously.

I have already searched registry and trash and scanned the `D:\Baz\Qux\` folder path with Recuva Undelete, but unfortunately found nothing this way.

Both the current and previous paths of that folder also are mirrored (saved) to OneDrive. However, I believe that OneDrive does not provide a version history of folders, nor of files that have been renamed/moved.

Are there any other Windows caches etc. where such old paths could still be found?

Answer (score 1):

Two things to try:

- Look in the last disk image you made. Just mount the image as a drive, using whatever tool you used to make it. Search on that image... slow, because unindexed, but *certain* to find it, **if** you saved the partition used for D:.
- If the change was made only recently, and you have been using an indexed search tool, such as DocFetcher or Windows Search, perform a search on the folder, or on a file or key words you know will be found in that folder. Hopefully, the search will produce at least one invalid result, i.e., showing the data in the old path.
- If there are files in the old location that have been opened in a particular application, such as a PDF or EPUB viewed in Okular, look at the most recent file list (MRU). Of course, the old folder may have dropped off the list if you've viewed many files since.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent suggestions!   
I just found the old folder name (see my answer to the original question:)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have solved the problem. Fortunately, my synchronization program GoodSync creates detailed log files with all file/folder operations performed.

In those log files, it was relatively easy to find out what the folder `fubar` was called previously.